# how to generate unique accountid in user model which should be auto generated after user registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

**This is my models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import UserManager


# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):   
    account_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=1111111)
    log_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=0000000)
       
    username = None 
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   
        
    objects = UserManager()
        
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

From this code, I am able to make an account id from the admin panel but I want to generate a unique account id automatically when users fill out the registration form it should generate a unique account id in the admin panel.

**This is my tools.py file**

````
from random import randint
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

def User():
    def account_id():
        account_id = randint(1000000, 9999999)
        print(account_id)
        is_unique = User.objects.filter(account_id=account_id).exists()
        if not User.account_id:
            is_unique = False
            while not is_unique:
                account_id
            User.account_id = account_id
            User.save()
        else:
            account_id()    
    User.save()            
      ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to use a [UUID field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) on the model like e.g.

```
import uuid

class User(AbstractUser):   
    account_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    
    ...
```

Note that most of the times it might be sufficient to just use the default ID of the model to distinguish between instances.

Comment: yes that is also the way but I want to make it without UUID, Is there any other way to make it?? anyway thank you JSRB

Comment: there are hundreds of ways - but why don't you want to use the safest, easiest and most convenient one? If you want to assign your generated one you will have to overwrite the save method on the user class.